# Organizing Your Pages

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, urls, child-pages

I'm having problems creating sub pages. So far I've followed the proper directions:

1. Go to a new page, click the "Page Parent" drop-down menu.
2. Select the
   appropriate parent Page from the drop-down menu to make the current
   Page a child Page.
3. Click Publish when ready.

When I do publish the page, It results in page not found. For example:

Suppose I had a page South America and I add 'child' pages:

South America

- Argentina
- Brazil

When I go to www.mywebsite.com/SouthAmerica/Argentina

It says page not found.

However:

- www.mywebsite.com/SouthAmerica/ **(works)**
- www.mywebsite.com/Argentina/  **(works)**
- www.mywebsite.com/SouthAmerica/Argentina **(Does not Work)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing parent pages (hierarchy) with page slugs (the URL). Parent pages are designed to allow you to programmatically build things like menus/submenus and breadcrumbs.  Whereas a page slug is the visual representation in the URL.

Many times, of course, I'd recommend you make your page slug match your hierarchy (for the user experience), so I think you're half way there.

First ensure your permalinks are setup properly (system wide) in the Permalinks settings page:

[image: Permakink Settings]

Then in your child page, make sure the Permalink reflects the URL you're hoping to display (it's just under the page title).

Since you mentioned that www.mywebsite.com/Argentina/ works, I bet when you look at the permalink on the Argentina page, it'll show the Permalink as `http://www.mywebsite.com/Argentina/`